# SQL Order the calendar period using Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, date, sql-order-by

I'm new in sql and I have question, hope you can help me.

How can I order the below data by calendar period. The datatype is VarChar2

```
Jan-2020
Feb-2020
Mar-2019
Jan-2019
Feb-2019
Mar-2020
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Hi @GordonLinoff, I'm using the Oracle Database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can turn the string to a date `to_date()` and use it for ordering:

```
order by to_date(mycol, 'mon-yyyy')
```

If the language of your database or session is not English, you need an additional argument so Oracle can understand the month name:

```
    order by to_date(mycol, 'mon-yyyy', 'nls_date_language = american')
```

Comment: Hi, I tried this one and I got an error 'ORA-01843: not a valid month'

Comment: @Lawrencxe: presumably, your database's language is not English. I added a solution for that.

Comment: @Lawrencxe: that's one of the reasons why storing things like "month values" as a string is usually not a good idea. It would be better to store things like that as numbers